# Numpy indexing explanation

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

So I have a data set and when I run this code I get the following output:

```
X = my_data[['Age', 'Sex', 'BP', 'Cholesterol', 'Na_to_K']].values
X
```

[image]

now when I run the code:

```
X[:,1]
```

I perfectly get the list of all the values in the gender column. this is what I wanted but i dont know how I got it. can someone explain this? I'm new to this. Also can someone explain other cool things that can be done to get different outputs so that I can learn?

Comment: [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Answer (score 1):

`my_data` is a Pandas dataframe.  The first indexing, with a list of names, selects columns.  `.values` converts that data to a numpy array, `X`.

`X` is a 2d  object dtype array.

```
X[:, 1]
```

selects the values from column `1` (which counting from 0 is the 2nd).

```
my_data['Sex']
```

would have produced the same values, but in a pandas `Series` format.